# parsing xml in python tag specific

Tags: python, xml

This is my input file

```
<datasource formatted-name='federated.1819qwi0hys5391dzxhl70o95li4' inline='true' source-platform='win' version='18.1' xmlns:user='http://www.tableausoftware.com/xml/user'>
  <connection class='federated'>
    <named-connections>
      <named-connection caption='Sample - Superstore' name='excel.1ew9u4t0tggb9315darmm0nfz2kb'>
        <connection class='excel' driver='' filename='C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/Sample - Superstore.xls' header='yes' imex='1' password='' server='' />
      </named-connection>
    </named-connections>
    <relation connection='excel.1ew9u4t0tggb9315darmm0nfz2kb' name='Custom SQL Query' type='text'>SELECT [Orders$].[Category] AS [Category],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[City] AS [City],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Country] AS [Country],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Customer ID] AS [Customer ID],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Customer Name] AS [Customer Name],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Discount] AS [Discount],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Profit] AS [Profit],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Quantity] AS [Quantity],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Region] AS [Region],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[State] AS [State],&#13;&#10;  [People$].[Person] AS [Person],&#13;&#10;  [People$].[Region] AS [Region (People)]&#13;&#10;FROM [Orders$]&#13;&#10;  INNER JOIN [People$] ON [Orders$].[Region] = [People$].[Region]</relation>
    <metadata-records>
      <metadata-record class='column'>
        <remote-name>Category</remote-name>
        <remote-type>130</remote-type>
        <local-name>[Category]</local-name>
        <parent-name>[Custom SQL Query]</parent-name>
        <remote-alias>Category</remote-alias>
        <ordinal>1</ordinal>
        <local-type>string</local-type>
        <aggregation>Count</aggregation>
        <contains-null>true</contains-null>
        <collation>LEN_RUS_S2_WO</collation>
        <attributes>
          <attribute datatype='string' name='DebugRemoteType'>&quot;WSTR&quot;</attribute>
        </attributes>
      </metadata-record>
```

I want to get the **attribute** tag . I Have tried

```
for x in xmlRoot.findall('./metadata-record'):
            sqlString=x.find('attribute').text
```

but im getting only space as result. I have changed all the possible combinations in findall , still not able to get the result . I want to read that attribute tag dynamically and write in the output file as same . I have retrived the other tags from metadata-record but this alone not working. Can some one help ??

My expected output is

```
<metadata-records>
      <metadata-record class='column'>
        <remote-name>Category</remote-name>
        <remote-type>130</remote-type>
        <local-name>[Category]</local-name>
        <parent-name>[Custom SQL Query]</parent-name>
        <remote-alias>Category</remote-alias>
        <ordinal>1</ordinal>
        <local-type>string</local-type>
        <aggregation>Count</aggregation>
        <contains-null>true</contains-null>
        <collation>LEN_RUS_S2_WO</collation>
        <attributes>
          <attribute datatype='string' name='DebugRemoteType'>&quot;WSTR&quot;</attribute>
        </attributes>
      </metadata-record>
```

I have retrieved till **collation** tag but do not know how to get the **attributes** tag. Can someone help??

Thanks,
Aarush

Comment: Please explain a little further: you are looking for the <attribute> tag, but how does that combine with your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, you can try something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlRoot = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(''.join([ET.tostring(x, encoding="unicode") for x in xmlRoot.findall('.//metadata-records//*')]))
```

Where `xml` is your xml input data.

Key is the `findall`: It looks from the root for any subelement called `metadata-records` and from that it just looks for any element.

The double forward slash `//` makes sure not only direct children are found, but any descendant of the `metadata-records` element. That is why you did find the `<attributes>` element (child), but failed to find the `<attribute>` element (child of child)

Answer (score 1):

#### Fix XML

First, I would fix the input file. It is not a good xml as it is missing some closing tags.

I fixed it for you here

```
<datasource formatted-name='federated.1819qwi0hys5391dzxhl70o95li4' inline='true' source-platform='win' version='18.1' xmlns:user='http://www.tableausoftware.com/xml/user'>
  <connection class='federated'>
    <named-connections>
      <named-connection caption='Sample - Superstore' name='excel.1ew9u4t0tggb9315darmm0nfz2kb'>
        <connection class='excel' driver='' filename='C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/Sample - Superstore.xls' header='yes' imex='1' password='' server='' />
      </named-connection>
    </named-connections>
    <relation connection='excel.1ew9u4t0tggb9315darmm0nfz2kb' name='Custom SQL Query' type='text'>SELECT [Orders$].[Category] AS [Category],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[City] AS [City],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Country] AS [Country],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Customer ID] AS [Customer ID],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Customer Name] AS [Customer Name],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Discount] AS [Discount],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Profit] AS [Profit],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Quantity] AS [Quantity],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[Region] AS [Region],&#13;&#10;  [Orders$].[State] AS [State],&#13;&#10;  [People$].[Person] AS [Person],&#13;&#10;  [People$].[Region] AS [Region (People)]&#13;&#10;FROM [Orders$]&#13;&#10;  INNER JOIN [People$] ON [Orders$].[Region] = [People$].[Region]
    </relation>
  </connection>
    <metadata-records>
      <metadata-record class='column'>
        <remote-name>Category</remote-name>
        <remote-type>130</remote-type>
        <local-name>[Category]</local-name>
        <parent-name>[Custom SQL Query]</parent-name>
        <remote-alias>Category</remote-alias>
        <ordinal>1</ordinal>
        <local-type>string</local-type>
        <aggregation>Count</aggregation>
        <contains-null>true</contains-null>
        <collation>LEN_RUS_S2_WO</collation>
        <attributes>
          <attribute datatype='string' name='DebugRemoteType'>&quot;WSTR&quot;</attribute>
        </attributes>
      </metadata-record>
    </metadata-records>
</datasource>
```

#### Now to use minidom to traverse the XML

1. import the minidom module from xml.dom
2. parse the xml (I just saved it to my file system as *x.xml*)
3. Get the element you are looking for with `getElementsByTagName`

Here is my code

```
from xml.dom import minidom

mydoc = minidom.parse('x.xml')

items = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('attribute')

print(items)
```

`print(items)` will print the object `[<DOM Element: attribute at 0x10aad6690>]`
To get the values inside, you need to print the contents of this object which is a nodelist.
Do this to get the value between the tags

```
# Traverse the childNodes of the tag
for t in items[0].childNodes:
    # if the node is a text node then print it
    if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE:
        print(t.nodeValue)
```

**One Liner**

```
print(''.join((t.nodeValue for t in items[0].childNodes if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE)))
```

This page really helped me get started with XML parsing [Reference page](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks much for the help